# Convert base 64 file to text or pdf file in r

Tags: r, base64, file-manipulation

I am using R, version 3.3.2.. I have downloaded base64 file from API. Here is output (base64) file (all file have 27 pages so I put just liitle part of it):

```
list(structure(list("584959666b2e5f32bc43fad1", "584959666b2e5f32bc43fad1.pdf", 
    91572L, "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 ", 
    "application/pdf"), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("dokumentId", "filename", "lenght", "content", "contentType"
    ))))
```

I would like to convert this file to text or pdf file, and then parse it. I have tried to use two packages but without success: `base64enc` and `base64`.
For example I have tried:

```
text <- document[[1]][[4]]
plain_text <- base64enc::base64decode(text)
plain_text <- rawToChar(plain_text)
```

and

```
text <- document[[1]][[4]]
test_file <- write.csv2(text, "E:/somepath/test_file.csv")
tmp <- tempfile()
base64::decode(input = test_file, output = tmp)
```

, but without success. Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what *"but without success"* means. Did your code return error messages, or just incorrect output?

Comment: In first part, `plain_text <- base64enc::base64decode(text)` returns some raw vector [1:91572] with integers as elements. This is why I have used function  `rawToChar(plain_text)` to convert it to string, but it returns an error `Error in rawToChar(plain_text) :embedded nul in string:`.

Comment: I tried to convert the provided string using both http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp and http://base64converter.com/, but the result is an invalid pdf...

Comment: maybe because I haven't paste the hole document?

Comment: @Mislav You have a nul character (`\0`) somewhere in your real data. You're sample data is malformed (presumably the text string is too long for the interpreter) so I can't test this, but try something like `rawToChar(setdiff(plain_text, as.raw(0)))`.

Comment: it gives some strange string. How should I approach in general? What if I jus4t want to save this base 6 file as pdf file?